# How to set up realtime object detection with custom dataset using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I need to set up a project for realtime object detection with custom dataset using a webcam on OpenCV. What framework should i use for this and what is the proceduce for training and code?

I had used haarcascade but it was very inaccurate and also efficientdet but it was very slow.

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask] (question lacks detail, data, research), [help/on-topic] (asking for recommendations)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.